# rails 3, check against two conditions using ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I need to implement a query that checks two ids inside all records of a table,
I am trying the following query, but, Its not correct:

```
if StudentsCourses.all.where(:student_id == current_student.id && :course_id == session[:course_id]).count != 0

# do something
end
```

where student_id and course_id are foreign keys inside StudentsCourses

also, is there a better way rather than check result count not equal zero ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unless StudentsCourses.where(:student_id => current_student.id, :course_id => session[:course_id]).empty?
  # do something
end
```

You were close!

Comment: thanks! I am just new to activerecord, I appreciate the quick response!